Testing an element outside of the root div, is it possible?
I'm using yet-another-react-lightbox and need to write a basic test that make sure that the light box opens upon a button click.
Upon click the library adds the element to the DOM, yet outside of the root div and I fail to capture these elements.
Is there a way to access these elements?
Lightbox open:
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div></div>
</body>

Lightbox closed:
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>


Consider sharing how you are rendering the component. Also try using the portal prop in the Lightbox component.

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
